# SQL being a jerk again

Tags: sql

I have the script I use that displays things from a table in my database, but it keeps giving me this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\raynerblogger1\posts.php on line 21

someone please help

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogs;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div id='message'>";
    echo $row['author']; echo(':') . "<br>";
    echo $row['post'] . "</div>" . "<br>" . "<br>" . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `$result` is false because the query failed.

Comment: @MattClark How do I fix it?

Comment: Check why the query failed. `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: Remove that semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I edited line 1 and 6:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogs";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div id='message'>";
    echo $row['author'].":". "<br>";
    echo $row['post'] . "</div>" . "<br>" . "<br>" . "<br>";
}
```